# Appending to an element in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set up an array of elements containing the alphabet and am trying to append each value as a hyperlink using jquery. I can see my values in the array, but on my page they are showing up as undefined. Can someone shed a little light? thanks.

```
<p id="alphabet"><a href="#" class="alphaChar"></a></p>
<script>
   var alph = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P",     "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "W", "X","Y","Z"];
   $.each(alph, function(index, value){
   $("a .alphaChar").append().html( "<a href='"#"' class='alphaClass'>  " +  alph.val + "</a>" );
});
</script>
```

Comment: The `'"#"'` seems like a bad string inside the `<a>` element you're building.

Comment: `alph.val` change to `value`

Comment: Never append elements to the DOM in a loop!

Comment: the .value didnt do anything

Comment: Also, you're going to want `$("a.alphaChar")`. With the space in between you're saying find a descendent of `a` that is classed as `.alphaChar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a number of problems,

Use `value` instead of alph.val,

your selector was wrong, (You were looking for children with class alphachar)

```
$("a.alphaChar")
```

and your `.append().html(..)` was wrong  -you can chain functions in JQuery, so what you were actually doing was "Append nothing, and THEN set the HTML of the entire element to ...".

```
$("a.alphaChar").append( < HTML GOES HERE > );
```

**See this fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/wW5CZ/

```
var alph = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];

$.each(alph, function (index, value) {
    console.log(value);
    $("a.alphaChar").append("<a href='\"#\"' class='alphaClass'>  " + value + "</a>");
});
```

Comment: One comment here actually - you're appending all of these links to the main link,... is that correct? or do you want to add these UNDER the alphachar main link.  (if you want it UNDER the alphachar link then use `.after` instead of `.append`

Answer (score 2):

Rather than appending it a loop, build your entire DOM element and append at the end:

```
var html = ""
$.each(alph, function(index, value){
    html += "<a href='#' class='alphaChar'>  " +  value + "</a>" );
});

$("a.alphaChar").append(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some syntax error in your code I think you want to do this :

**JavaScript:**

```
var alph = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",   "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "W", "X","Y","Z"];
$.each(alph, function(index, value){
   $("a.alphaChar").append("<a href='#' class='alphaClass'>  " +  value + "</a>" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
var alph = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P","Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "W", "X","Y","Z"];
for (var i=0; i < alph.length; i++) {
    $("a .alphaChar").append($("<a href='#' class='alphaClass'>" +  alph[i] + "</a>" ));
}
```